# Displaytag: how to specify column data type as "Text"

Tags: java, excel, jsp, displaytag

I'm using DisplayTag to export some data to an Excel file. I have a column which contains long numeric codes, like '740760000000001': they should be rendered as they are, but Excel tries to be smarter and shows 7,4076E+14 instead.

How to tell DisplayTag to export a column as plain text?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this day? I'm having the same problem and can't find anything around on the internet

Comment: @L_Cleo In the end I think I just used the old trick of putting a ' before the value. I had to use separate columns for displaying and for exporting.

Comment: Well, this morning I've found a better way, but you will have to have two columns. One for the excel and one for the html. If you're interested, you can use the 'format' property of the display tag. This way you can use format='="{0}" ' , basically the ="something" tells excel that it's a text data type. the only problem is that on the html you will see the ="" too, so you have to put a column with the format property set and media type to excel and the other column without the format but with media set to html
I might answer to your question for everybody else

Answer (score -2):

By default the format of excel column is set to exponential format.Select the whole column where you displaying 740760000000001 and right click then select format cells,select Numbers and make decimal place:0 and select (1234) black highlighted section .
You work is done
                   All the best

Comment: You are describing how Excel works. But I don't have any control over the file once the user has exported it. The file needs to be created with the correct cell format already set.